# error initializing configuration envoy.yaml Failed to load pkcs12 from /etc/cert.p12

Tags: networking, tls1.2, envoyproxy, pkcs#12

This is what i want to reach with envoy as proxy for https traffic:
[image]

I got the certificate (p12) from the java developer to load it with envoy, then make developer happy by hitting envoy without certificate (on port 8080). Check diagram above also.

In order to do that this is my `envoy.yaml`

```yaml
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 8080
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          codec_type: AUTO
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: app
              domains:
              - "*"
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/"
                route:
                  cluster: api-example-https
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.http.router
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router

  clusters:
  - name: api-example-https
    type: STRICT_DNS
    lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: api-example-https
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: api.example.com
                port_value: 443
    transport_socket:
      name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
      typed_config:
        "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.UpstreamTlsContext
        common_tls_context:
          tls_certificates:
          - pkcs12:
              filename: /etc/cert.p12
```

Unfortunately, i am getting this error:

```
[2022-11-01 22:17:48.788][1][critical][main] [source/server/server.cc:117] error initializing configuration '/etc/envoy.yaml': Failed to load pkcs12 from /etc/cert.p12
[2022-11-01 22:17:48.788][1][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:961] exiting
Failed to load pkcs12 from /etc/cert.p12
```

What am i missing ? 3 hours troubleshooting but no way :(

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the `certificate` has to be used alongside a `password`.

And i verified that by using curl on the external service directly:

```bash
curl --cert-type P12 --cert 'cert.p12:MyPass' https://api.example.com
```

This means that `envoy.yaml` must include the configuration of a password.
Hence, the config file should looks like:

```yaml
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 8080
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          codec_type: AUTO
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: app
              domains:
              - "*"
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/"
                route:
                  cluster: api-example-https
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.http.router
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router

  clusters:
  - name: api-example-https
    type: STRICT_DNS
    lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: api-example-https
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: api.example.com
                port_value: 443
    transport_socket:
      name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
      typed_config:
        "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.UpstreamTlsContext
        common_tls_context:
          tls_certificates:
          - pkcs12:
              filename: /etc/cert.p1
            password:
              inline_string: MyPass ###  Fixed By adding this
```

REF: https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/v3/common.proto#envoy-v3-api-field-extensions-transport-sockets-tls-v3-tlscertificate-pkcs12

> Use password to specify the password to unprotect the PKCS12 data, if necessary.